# Web3: Extract data from soliditySha3

Tags: node.js, solidity, smartcontracts

Let's say I call the following function to generate a hashed message for generating a signature.

```js
function signMessage(recipient, amount, newNonce, contract, type) {
    const msgHash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(
        { t: "address", v: recipient },
        { t: "uint256", v: amount },
        { t: "string", v: newNonce },
        { t: "address", v: contract },
        { t: "uint256", v: type }
    ) || ""

    return web3.eth.accounts.sign(msgHash, privateKey);
}
```

On Solidity smart contract, how should I extract each information (for example, the "type") from that signature?

Comment: you cant reverse a hash to get the value

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for letting me know that. Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I dont think that you can reverse the hash value. Hash functions are one way. You probably wanted to sign the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the hashed value is not reversable, but I can use the same variables to hash again on the smart contract and check if the two hashed values are the same, so I can know the value is transferred correctly.